# Clicking the navigation with corresponding message (without reloading page)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two pages: HOME and VOTE. My goal is that, when I click the VOTE navigation, it should prompt me with the message that I can't vote (without reloading page). Then, it will redirect/go to the HOME page.

I tried this statement, but it reloads the page instead of giving me the prompt I want.

VOTE page:

```
<?php
$session_id=$_SESSION['std_id'];
$sql= "select * from tbl_student WHERE std_id='$session_id'  AND std_status='Unvoted' AND validate ='Unenrolled'";
    $query = $con->query($sql); 
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count==1){  
echo "Sorry, You are not enrolled in this semester <br> You are no longer to vote or proceed to Cast Vote. Thank you.";// what codes should I replace for this?
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=home.php">'; // what codes should I replace for this?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=home.php">'; // what codes should I replace for this?
```

to

```
header( 'Location: home.php' );
```

The Complete Code:

```
<?php
$session_id=$_SESSION['std_id'];
$sql= "select * from tbl_student WHERE std_id='$session_id'  AND std_status='Unvoted' AND validate ='Unenrolled'";
    $query = $con->query($sql); 
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count==1){  
echo "Sorry, You are not enrolled in this semester <br> You are no longer to vote or proceed to Cast Vote. Thank you.";
header( 'Location: home.php' );
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

If you need to display a message and later redirect you should use this:

```
<?php
$session_id=$_SESSION['std_id'];
$sql= "select * from tbl_student WHERE std_id='$session_id'  AND  std_status='Unvoted' AND validate ='Unenrolled'";
$query = $con->query($sql); 
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count==1) {
    echo "Sorry, You are not enrolled in this semester <br> You are no longer to vote or proceed to Cast Vote. Thank you.";
}
?>
<script>setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "home.php";
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Project_OVS\cast_vote.php:63) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project_OVS\cast_vote.php on line 87

Comment: I should have to print :   echo 'Sorry, You are not enrolled in this semester <br> You are no longer to vote or proceed to Cast Vote. Thank you'  first before go back to home back withoout reloading the page.

Comment: if you want to display the message and later redirect you need to use JS. Let me edit my code